# Where to implement repeating logics like sharing an image in RN?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

The user can share an image in my app. This can be done by longpress the list item or with a button in the details-screen, which appears after clicking a list-item.

For the rows (list-items) I have an own container and for the details screen.

Where should I place the sharing logic? Sharing could be replaced with any other actions I use in the app at different places **without** effect on the redux store.

- Opening an address in Google Maps or Apple Maps
- Calling a phone number
- Save an image to the device storage
- ...

At the moment I see three options:

**Actions, Middleware, Helper-classes** ?

But what would be the best way?

Comment: I ask myself the same question. Where to write code that is unrelated to Redux ecosystem? I personally write utils/helper functions for that purpose. Waiting for other suggestions as well.

Comment: I will vote for utils and helper. Unrelated redux code should be in one of these or `services`

Comment: What exactly do you mean with services? Just another naming for a helper-class or how would your implement it?

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing right now is that I have a  BaseComponent that extends the normal React Native component and then I make all the other components extend my BaseComponent instead of the regular RN one.

That way I can share functions I normally use, like getting a composed style, react to actions like links, popups, etc.

If you have a lot of code/functions that belong to a particualr category then yes, I make another Helper and the BaseComponent holds a reference to that helper.

So, when I need it, I know I can call something like this.getHelper() and any component will have access to that helper or functions.

Answer (score -1):

You should put these in a ***higher order component (HOC)***, and use it to decorate a component with those functionalities.

```js
@shareable
class ImageItem extend React.Component {
  render() {
    const {handleShare} = this.props // injected by @shareable
    const {imgSrc} = this.props
    return(
      <div>
        <img src={imgSrc}/>
        <button onClick={handleShare}>Share</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This react pattern is great for creating reusable data/behavioral models for components.